# How can I prevent shift of the input element inside parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div that contains three elements.

Here is the div:

```
<div id="toolbarArea" class="toolbarArea" data-Owner="geomind" data-Date="11/2016"> 
                        <img id="toolbarTitle" width="15px" height="15px" src="../stdicons/threePoints.png">
                    <iframe id="frTools" style="width:400px;height:25px;overflow: hidden;" name="tbFrame" src="/data/mapview/toolbar.aspx?LOCALE=en" frameBorder="0"></iframe>

  <input type="text" id="txtSearch" placeholder="Sample Input"/>

</div>
```

The input text that inside div is shifted.Here how it looks:

[image]

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6na2pt5/).

How can I prevent shift down of the input element and make it fit parent element?

Comment: What do you mean by shifted?

Comment: @DNKROZ it's shifted down. And I need it to fill parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `vertical-align: top;` to the input field:

```
#txtSearch {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: If the parent is a fixed height, you can play with the padding of the input. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/ay5sm2ky/. Alternatively you can use `height: 100%;` with `box-sizing:border-box;` like https://jsfiddle.net/Lz31qngf/